# How to display jsp page that controller returns with angularjs

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, jsp

I have a controller that returns jsp page. So how can I make request from angularjs and display that page in browser?

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("user/{username}")
public String showUserDetails(@PathVariable String username, Model model) throws SQLException {
    model.addAttribute("userDetails",dbHelper.getUser(username));
    return "/profile.jsp";
}
```

Angularjs:

```
$scope.openProfile = function(username){

        $http.get("/root/services/rest/user/" + username);

    }
```

When I call this function from jsp, I get jsp page in response, but it is not being displayed in browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller will return the string of url or view name then you can change url via `$location` or `$window` 
other wise your can also use `ui-view` or `ng-view` for the change view/route.

Comment: But `$location.path` only adds up to existing url, and doesn't refresh the page.

Comment: use $state.transitionTo with reload